# Is there any standard SNMP MIB for storage arrays?

Tags: storage, snmp

I want to implement SNMP agent for storage array product my company develops. I'm wonder if there is industry-standard SNMP MIB that I need to implement?

Comment: If it is part of the standard, you can search at http://tools.ietf.org/

Comment: Not all of the ietf stuff is industry-standard. I was asking if there is any MIB that is de-facto standard for storage array management.

Comment: I'm not aware of any. Check what the competition is doing. I think that EMC, for example, are using proprietary MIBs that they developed themselves.